# Swift 4: access IBAction sender from another function?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on card game app and I set the `dealThreeMore` `sender` to disabled when the we run out of `game.cards`.

When I reset the game however I'm not sure how to access this sender button to reenable it. Is there some way I can access it without the user actually pressing this button and outside of the `dealThreeMore` func?

[Github](https://github.com/turnipdabeets/Set/blob/master/Set/ViewController.swift)

```
@IBAction func dealThreeMore(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // have a match and cards available to deal
        if !matched.isEmpty && !game.cards.isEmpty {
            clearAndDeal()
        } else {
            // deal three more cards
            //TODO: make sure no set exists before allow dealing more?
            deal()
        }
        // disable if we run out of cards
        if game.cards.isEmpty {
            disable(button: sender)
            resetInfoLabel()
        }
    }

private func disable(button sender: UIButton){
    sender.isEnabled = false
    sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 0.5160798373)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `@IBOutlet` property to keep a reference to your button.

`@IBoutlet weak var mMyButton : UIButton?`

Then create the connection in your storyboard / xib file and you will be able to use `mMyButton.isSelected = false`

Comment: I was thinking about this but it felt off to make both an IBOutlet and an IBAction. Is this practice used commonly? I'm pretty new to iOS and swift.

Comment: This is fine.  There is nothing wrong with having both an `@IBOutlet` and an `@IBAction` for the same button.  They serve different purposes.

Comment: Go ahead and make it an *implicitly unwrapped optional*.  This is the standard practice for `@IBOutlet`s.